# How can I force SQL Server from SAP side to create a new plan?

Tags: sql-server, sap-basis

I created the perfect index for a query<sup>1</sup> that normally runs for more than a day. However, the new index is not picked by the optimizer, I suspect because it just re-uses the old plan.

I do not have DB level access, can I somehow make it pick a new plan from transaction ST04 (or DBACOCKPIT or DB02)?

---

1) with some outside help, that is not available any more

Comment: As a SAP user, you can't. If SAP used stored procedures (which it doesn't) then a DBA could `exec sp_recompile 'SomeStoredProcedureName'` which would cause a new plan to be generated next time that proc runs. The only alternatives are: let SQL server vacate the plan due to other memory pressure requirements; or `dbcc freeproccache` which dumps all plans from memory; or trip over the power cord.

Comment: You might be able to use Query Store to force the desired plan. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

DB20-> rebuilding statistic of table make rebuild execution plan in next call time.